# Computing a double integral with applications to prime numbers

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, prime-numbers, computer-algebra-systems

I was reading the preprint [1] which contains on p. 7 the following formula (for $4<s\le6$):
$$
f_1(s)=\frac{2e^\gamma}{s}\left\{\log(s-1)+\int_4^s\int_3^t\frac{\log(u-2)}{u-1}du\,dt \right\}
$$

and which concludes, on page 16, with
$$
c=\frac{2e^\gamma}{3f_1(6)}=1.18751\ldots.
$$

But evaluating the function numerically in PARI/GP

```
f1(s)=2*exp(Euler)/s*(log(s-1)+intnum(t=4,s,intnum(u=3,t,log(u-2)/(u-1))))
\p 200
2*exp(Euler)/3/f1(6)
```

gives me c = 0.8239599331..., a very different result. I tried it in Maxima

```
assume(t >= 4);
float(integrate(integrate(log(u-2)/(u-1),u,3,t),t,4,6));
```

and it gives 0.81786458079115, which corresponds to c = 1.4518071082, not very close to either result. (`bfloat` doesn't seem to work here -- it has trouble with the polylogarithms it seems.)

How can I reliable compute this double integral?

[1] Pin-Hung Kao, [Almost-Prime Polynomials with Prime Arguments](http://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03505), arXiv:1606.03505 [math.NT]

Comment: The result $0.817\ldots$ for the double-integral correponds to $c = 0.8239\ldots$ (the same as you got above) not $c=1.45$. The value $1.1875$ quoted in the paper is very very close to the value of $\frac{2e^{\gamma}}{3}$ so it's likely a mistake here where they forgot to divide by $f_1(6)$ when computing this.

Comment: @Winther: I did notice the closeness of the two, and wondered...

Comment: $\displaystyle{0.82395993312828650630536756797635658529658691543841}$.

Comment: $$ c =
\frac{12}{\pi ^2-6 \left(-5 \text{Li}_2(-4)+3 \text{Li}_2(-2)-2+\log(64/ 5)+\log(3) \log(8)-\log(5)\log(1024)\right)}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the authors might have used (I admit that the numbers do not match completely)
$$
c=\frac{2e^\gamma}{3F_1(6)}\approx1.18787
$$
(where $F_1$ is also defined on page 7) instead of
$$
c=\frac{2e^\gamma}{3f_1(6)}\approx 0.82396
$$
I don't have time or energy to understand which one is the correct one to put in the end. Mathematica calculates
$$
F_1(s)=\frac{1}{s}\bigl(2e^\gamma(1+\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\log(s-2)\log(s-1)+\text{Li}_2(2-s)\bigr)
$$
and 
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_1(s)&=\frac{2}s e^\gamma\Bigl(s-4+\frac{\pi^2}{12}s+\frac{5}{2}(\log 2)^2
+2\log 2-3\log2\log 3+\log(s-1)\\
&\quad +\log(s-2)(2-s+(s-1)\log(s-1))\\
&\quad+\text{Li}_2(-1/2)+\text{Li}_2(1/4)+(s-1)\text{Li}_2(2-s)\Bigr)
\end{aligned}
$$

This might be a mistake, and I suggest that you contact the author and ask.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Though it's tedious but the double integral is doable by subbing $u=1+x$ then repeating integration by parts several times. You might use the following relation
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=\int_z^0\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\ dx
\end{equation}